What is the time complexity of this function to compute equivalence classes using IORefs?
I've lifted the most relevant bits of code from the persistent-equivalence package. I've been staring at this for quite a long time and can't seem to figure out the time complexity of equateAll. I know that in the imperative world, union-find can be as fast as O(n) for versions that do path compression and union-by-rank.
{-|
    Construct the equivalence relation obtained by equating the given two
    values.  This combines equivalence classes.
-}
equate :: Ix i => i -> i -> Equivalence i -> Equivalence i
equate x y (Equivalence rs vps) = unsafePerformIO $ do
    ps <- readIORef vps
    let (ps',  px) = reprHelper ps                 x
        (ps'', py) = reprHelper (fromMaybe ps ps') y
    psFinal <- case ps' of
        Nothing -> do maybe (return ()) (writeIORef vps) ps''
                      return (fromMaybe ps ps'')
        Just t  -> do writeIORef vps (fromMaybe t ps'')
                      return (fromMaybe t ps'')
    return (go px py psFinal)
  where
    go px py ps
        | px == py  = Equivalence rs vps
        | rx > ry   = let ps' = ps // [(py, px)]
                      in Equivalence rs (ref ps')
        | rx < ry   = let ps' = ps // [(px, py)]
                      in Equivalence rs (ref ps')
        | otherwise = let ps' = ps // [(py, px)]
                          rs' = rs // [(px, (rx + 1))]
                      in Equivalence rs' (ref ps')
      where rx = rs ! px
            ry = rs ! py

{-|
    Construct the equivalence relation obtained by equating all of the given
    values.  This combines equivalence classes.
-}
equateAll :: Ix i => [i] -> Equivalence i -> Equivalence i
equateAll []     eq = eq
equateAll (x:xs) eq = foldl' (flip (equate x)) eq xs


Have you looked at the paper listed in the documentation?

Whoops! If you post this recommendation as an answer, I will accept it.
